# Executing multiple mysql queries from a shell script in a single statement

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to execute mysql queries from a shell script. Below are the two queries.The first one seems to work and gets the work done. The second statement fails. The second statement however works if I keep single query instead of two.

```
mysql-ib -utrial -ptrial! trial -se "SET @bh_dataformat='txt_variable'; SELECT @bh_dataformat"

$(mysql-ib -utrial -ptrial! trial -se "SET @bh_dataformat='txt_variable'; SELECT @bh_dataformat")
```

The error I get when I execute the second statement is

```
./test.sh: line 15: txt_variable: command not found
```

Comment: `$(cmd)` will execute `cmd` and the use the output if  `cmd` as a command name. Why are you using `$(...)` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl not something I have written. It came to me and I am trying to do things in the existing script. Not a shell expert. Should I not be using $(..)?

Comment: No, don't use `$(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a subshell with `$(..)`. That's why the calling's shell variables like `txt_variable` are not defined anymore.